# How to load the gif until the graph is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I wanted my gif to be loaded until the graph is loaded and then hide it .So I tried with the below command but it does not works as expected(GIF is showing but going after the graph loads).Below is my code:

```
    <div id='chartwrapper'>
    <div class='chartcurtain' style='height: 427px; width: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; text-align: center; line-height: 300px; font-size: 20px;'>


    </div>

    </div>
```

```
</div>
    </div>
     </div>
```

I added this in my graph

```
"listeners": [{
            "event": "rendered",
            "method": function(e) {
              var img_load = document.getElementById("img-load");
              img_load.parentElement.removeChild(curtain);
            }
      }],
```

But now initially the gif is there but after that the gif disappears and it did not appear until the next graph
 comes.Any help is appreciated

Comment: `<sript` is a typo and where did you call `loader();` function?

Comment: can you explain this "does not works as expected"?

Comment: where is the DOM element with id `result`?

Comment: have you gone through the API documentation of [tag:amcharts]? can you share the API documentation link?

Comment: @MohammadFaisal Is this what you nedded?[amcharts link](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts)

Comment: which kind of chart is this? there is a lot of list. perhaps you should look for the events section, like this one: https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmAngularGauge#rendered

Comment: @Josh does your chart loaded properly?

Comment: @AminurRashid Yes my chart loads properly

Comment: use event like 'drawn' or 'rendered' to identify when it's loaded completely and then hide the gif

Comment: @AminurRashid I updated the question.Could you help me now?

Comment: you said the gif is shown and then disappear after chart load, then what's the problem actually?

Comment: It should appear again when the next data is loaded.(Each data load it should appear on the screen)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136440/discussion-between-aminur-rashid-and-josh).

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted a working (or mostly working) fiddle that at least shows your page's workflow for rendering these charts. Are you calling makeChart after each getJSON? Are you updating the chart's data and calling validateData()? It's hard to say from what you have here and are several different ways you can go about it, but seeing a working example will help in giving you a targeted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var img_load=$('#img-load');
      $(img_load).show();
```

and

```
"listeners": [{
            "event": "drawn",
            "method": function(e) {
              //var img_load = document.getElementById("img-load");
              var img_load=$('#img-load');
              $(img_load).hide();
            }
          }
```

made the trick and worked like charm.Hope it helps anyone.